# Richardson extrapolation from from composite rule

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I have a composite quadrature rule whose error is $O(h^3)$ used to estimate an integral. I have for two values of h the values of that estimaton.

I am using Richardson extrapolation to improve the estimate of a definite integral.

I know that if we have a composite rule with degree of accuracy $p-1$ then,

$I(f)=I_{n}(f)+Ch^p+O(h^{p+1})$ which applying to two different n simplifies to:

$I(f)=\frac{h_2^pI_{n1}(f) - h_1^pI_{n2}(f)}{h_2^p - h_1^p}+O(h^{p+1})$

Now, I am just a bit confused if I should use p=4, from the initial condition stating that the accuracy is p-1 (p-1=3, so p=4), or if I should use p=2 from $O(h^{p+1})$ (p=1=3, so p=2).

Can you help?

Comment: Why are you using two different $n$ values and $h$ values at once? Why not just think of your composite rule as $F(h)$, then $F(h)=I(h)+Ch^3+o(h^3),F(h/2)=I(h)+Ch^3/8+o(h^3)$, hence $\frac{8F(h/2)-F(h)}{7}=I(h)+o(h^3)$? (Proceed analogously if your $h_1$ and $h_2$ are related in some different way.)

Comment: In other words I think you are not taking advantage of the abstraction that Richardson extrapolation is based on. The whole idea is that if $F(h)=I(h)+Ch^p+o(h^p)$ then you can choose a linear combination combination of $F(h_1)$ and $F(h_2)$ which is equal to $I(h)+o(h^p)$. This does not inherently have anything to do with integration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand what you are saying but I am currently studying and the way this problem is structured requires to use two values of h and its corresponding approximate integral values. Using my approach from what I have read, I am a bit confused regarding the value of p to use. Both provide an better estimation but I don't know which one is actually correct.

Comment: If your original method's overall error is third order then you use p=3.

Comment: But since I have in my formla $O(h^{p+1})$ should then be p=2 or 3, being the resulting $O(h^{4})$ ?

Comment: The new order depends on more than just the old order. If your method is such that Richardson extrapolation improves the order by 1 then your new method will be $O (h^4) $. But that may not necessarily occur. For example, each Richardson extrapolation of the trapezoidal rule improves the order by 2.